# I have lost the ‘seed keys’ (password) to my Mycelium soft wallet (which is on my old iPhone)

Tags: wallet-recovery, seed, mycelium-wallet

I purchased Bitcoin several years go, it is on a ‘soft wallet’ (Mycelium is the name of the wallet) on an old I phone that is no longer used. Is this Bitcoin in any way recoverable?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't write down the seed phrase, didn't write down the private key and didn't make a backup, you don't have any way to recreate your wallet and have lost control over any money.

A seed phrase is not a password.